# golang redis client connection status

Tags: go, redis, client, go-redis

After creting a new Redis client, is there a way to check the status of the connection?

As a way to ensure that the Sentinel is in a healthy state, a status check after instantiation would be ideal.

Comment: Some client libraries offer a `Ping()` method that executes Redis' `PING` command (https://redis.io/commands/ping) to check the status of the connection: `err := redisClient.Ping(ctx)`

Comment: Thank you @GastónPalomeque.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  If you submit an answer, I will mark it as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some client libraries offer a `Ping()` method that executes [Redis' `PING` command](https://redis.io/commands/ping) to check the status of the connection:

```golang
redisClient := redis.NewClient(...)
if err := redisClient.Ping(ctx); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: The error is ping: PONG in which is should be the state of OK.   am I wrong about that?

Comment: I dont understand how this can be the correct answer as Ping() returns PONG and thus the error wont be nil either way?

Comment: The naming of the return var here is confusing. `err` is actually a `StatusCmd`. In order to check the error you'd call `redisClient.Ping(ctx).Err()`

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the client you use.

For example, the radix client (https://github.com/mediocregopher/radix) support a function to monitor for checking the connection (error, reused, created and so on.)

Answer (score 0):

```
redisClient := redis.NewClient(...)
if err := redisClient.Ping(ctx).Err(); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [go-redis](https://github.com/redis/go-redis) client for connecting to redis then  you can try the following to check if redis is connected properly.

```
    client := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:     "localhost:6379",
        Password: "",
        DB:       0,
    })
    if pong := client.Ping(ctx); pong.String() != "ping: PONG" {
        log.Println("-------------Error connection redis ----------:", pong)
    }
```